# Prevent direct URL access with .htaccess

Tags: html

I know this question has been asked before several times, but I couldn't find the right answer.

I would like to allow search engines and some referrers to access a certain URL, without allowing direct URL access.

You can't reach this domain by clicking the link to

[2betist.umran.org](http://2betist.umran.org/)

When you search this domain on Google, you can reach the website by clicking the search result link, but accessing it directly via URL or via referrer doesn't work. I would like to create a white list on .htaccess for some of the referrers, along with the Google and Bing search engines.

I hope I describe the problem clearly enough. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! A lot of results here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=referrer+htaccess and try also this external link: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/ I think the answer relate to (external) proxies or loadbalancers which filter traffic. So, your html tag in your post is maybe not enough as you are not thinking far enough.

Comment: Thanks Christian , it was my first post .. as you say ma be html tag is not enough ..

Comment: No worries. I definitely learned something, as you can see in my answer below. The html tag might indeed be sufficient though.

Answer (score 0):

I have googled and found https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005257234-Introduction-to-htaccess-rewrite-rules which states:

> The .htaccess file controls a number of ways that a website can be accessed, blocked, and redirected. It does this using a series of one or more rewrite rules. These rewrites are made possible by Apache's mod_rewrite module.
>
> mod_rewrite provides a way to modify incoming URL requests, dynamically, based on regular expression rules. This allows you to map arbitrary URLs onto your internal URL structure in any way you like.
>
> The basic formulation of any .htaccess rewrite rule includes setting a combination of rewrite condition (RewriteCond) tests along with a corresponding rule (RewriteRule) if the prior conditions pass. In most cases, these rules should be placed at any point after the RewriteEngine on line in the .htaccessfile located in the website's docroot.

The keys are htaccess rewrite conditions and rules.

Another website provided an example for a .htaccess file to disallow certain referrers.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} / [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.semalt\.com [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} best-seo-solution\.com [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} best-seo-offer\.com [OR,NC]
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} OrgProbe [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Majestic [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

Here you can find the complete [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).